# Grep Entire File For Strings, Not Line by Line

Tags: grep

I am wanting to search for files that contain 'even:suspendcount>0' AND 'even:holdcount>0'. These 2 strings of text must be somewhere in the file, not necessarily on the same line. The problem I am running into is that my search results are not pulling back files that contain 1 sting of text on say line #5 and the other on line #10. It is only pulling back files if they are on the same line number. How would I search for files that contains multiple strings of text just somewhere in the file, they do not have to be on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using grep

To use grep to get files that have **both** strings in **either** order:

```
grep -lZ 'even:suspendcount>0'  * | xargs --null grep -l 'even:holdcount>0'
```

How it works:

- `grep -lZ 'even:suspendcount>0' *`

  This returns a nul-separated list of the names of files which contain the string `even:suspendcount>0`.
- `xargs --null grep -l 'even:holdcount>0'`

  Of the files selected by the first step, this returns the names of files which **also** contain `even:holdcount>0`

  Because we are using nul-separation when passing the file names from one process to the next, this approach is safe even for difficult file names.

#### Using awk

This prints the file name of any file that contains both strings:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{f=0;g=0} /even:suspendcount>0/{f=1} /even:holdcount>0/{g=1} f && g{print FILENAME; nextfile}' *
```

How it works:

- `BEGINFILE{f=0;g=0}`

  As we start reading a new file, variables `f` and `g` are set to zero (false).
- `/even:suspendcount>0/{f=1}`

  If we encounter a line containing `even:suspendcount>0`, then set variable `f` to 1.
- `/even:holdcount>0/{g=1}`

  Similarly, f we encounter a line containing `even:holdcount>0`, then set variable `g` to 1.
- `f && g{print FILENAME; nextfile}`

  If both `f` and `g` are true (nonzero), then print the filename and skip to the next file.

Comment: Thanks this worked like a charm. I thought I could get the rest if I just figured out that bit but now running into another issue when I attempt to search for files also containing 'scheduleelement' PLUS the other 2 I have already mentioned. The below code is what I am using and it is displaying files but appears to be displaying them all as one file name, just on separate lines. I get a message on the last line of 'File name too long'

grep -lZ 'scheduleelement' * | xargs --null grep -l 'even:suspendcount>0' | xargs --null grep -l 'even:holdcount>0'

Comment: @TAnderson You were very very close.  We need to tell the second `grep` to generate nul-separated output.  So, replace `-l` with `-lZ` for the second `grep`: `grep -lZ 'scheduleelement' * | xargs --null grep -lZ 'even:suspendcount>0' | xargs --null grep -l 'even:holdcount>0'`

Answer (score 0):

A `grep` pattern is line-oriented, i.e. in your case it should be 'even:suspendcount>0' **OR** 'even:holdcount>0' (namely `grep -E 'even:(suspend|hold)count>0'`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. With this would it not display files that have either 1 or both? I thought I had taken a look at this option but it was pulling files that had 'even:suspendcount>0' but 'even:holddcount>1' and was doing so because of the OR. I need to only display files that have both strings of text but they do not have to be on the same line

Comment: @TAnderson Fair point. A one-line approach is then `[ $(... | grep -Eo 'even:(suspend|hold)count>0' | sort -u | wc -l) = 2 ]` (i.e. there's at least one `hold` match and at least one `suspend` one).